# How to get the index of a number in input in Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The user needs to put a number and the code gets five digits, how do I make to only take four digits if the user only puts four?

Here it is:

```
numero = int(input("por favor ingrese un numero: "))

digito1 = numero // 10000
digito2 = (numero//1000) % 10
digito3 = (numero//100) % 10
digito4 = (numero//10) % 10
digito5 = numero % 10

if digito5 is None and digito1 == digito4 and digito2==digito3:
   print ("Es capicua")

if digito1 == digito5 and digito2 == digito4:
   print ("Es capicua")
else:
   print ("No es capicua")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to check if `numero` is a palindrome. That can be done in a simpler:

```
numero = int(float(input("por favor ingrese un numero: ")))
if str(numero)==str(numero)[::-1]: 
    print("Es capicua")
else: 
    print("No es capicua")
```

Comment: and how do this cheack the number of int that i put in?

Comment: I'm sorry, what? From the code you showed and the translation of 'capicua' I found, I guessed that you want to find out if `numero` read forewards is the same as read backwards (then it is a palindrome). These three lines of code don't test `numero` to any other properties.

Comment: For a certain value of `numero` (e.g. `1234`), try printing `str(numero)` and `str(numero)[::-1]`. In the example, you'll get `'1234'` and `'4321'`. If you now compare these two, the first character of both is compared (`'1' != '4'`), the second one is compared (`'2' != '3'`) and so on. So this does the same thing as your code but for any number of digits by using strings instead of integers.

Comment: thats what I wanted thanks for answering and your patience!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand 'capicua' so I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but it looks like you want to print 'Es capicua' if an integer is symmetrical around the middle (eg if you have 1221 or 12321) and 'No es capicua' if it is not symmetrical around the middle (eg 1234 or 12345).

The below will do this, and is generalised for different length integers.

```
numero = int(float(input("por favor ingrese un numero: ")))

digitos = list(str(numero))

symmetricalAroundMedian = True
for i in range(0,int(len(digitos)/2)):
    if digitos[i] != digitos[len(digitos)-1-i]:
        symmetricalAroundMedian = False

if symmetricalAroundMedian:
    print ("Es capicua")
else:
    print ("No es capicua")
```

Comment: yes i'm trying to do that, but as you see in my code only works if you put 5 numbers, thanks, could you explain this part? for i in `range(0,int(len(digitos)/2)):
    if digitos[i] != digitos[len(digitos)-1-i]:
        symmetricalAroundMedian = False`

Comment: The answer above is better so I would use that, but essentially the above code is saying: loop through each element (number) in the list from the start to the middle of the list (number), and if the first element (number) is not equal to the last element (number), the number is not a palindrome, then likewise if the second element (number) is not equal to the second last element (number) then the number is not a palindrome and so forth until you get to the middle. But as I say, the answer above is cleaner.